# Откуда bash узнаёт про цели Makefile?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

Makefile:

```
ab:

bc:

ce:
```

$ make (нажимаем tab)

bash подсказывает:

```
ab bc ce
```

Как bash про это узнаёт? Или make?

Comment: `bash-completion` пакет стоит? Вот он там миллион скриптов на случаи жизни держит. Можно, кстати, кастомизировать любые свои скрипты (глобальный умеет включать пользовательские в себя при входе в систему).

Answer (score 3):

На ОС *Ubuntu 18.04* файл со скриптом находится
в `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make`.  Скрипт
содержит более 200 строчек, и если вам интересно, можете его разобрать.
Если же коротко, это сочетание кода для `sed` и *Bash*.